# How to use jQuery confirm box to delete a row from database in zend?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I am new to Zend Framework and jQuery. I am trying to delete a row from database on the basis of the returned value of `confirm()`. But the problem I am having is that if I press yes or no both times the selected row is deleted. I need to confirm that only when I press yes that only the selected row will be deleted. One thing I am using Zend Framework.

My codes are given below:

### index.phtml

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
#simplemodal-overlay {background-color:#000;}
#simplemodal-container {background-color:#333; border:8px solid #444; padding:12px;}
#simplemodal-container a.modalCloseImg {
    background:url(x.png) no-repeat; /* adjust url as required */
    width:25px;
    height:29px;
    display:inline;
    z-index:3200;
    position:absolute;
    top:-15px;
    right:-18px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

</style> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jQuery.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.simplemodal-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){
    //alert("test");
    $(".delete").click(function(e){
        //$('p').attrib('id');
        //e.preventDefault();
        //$("#deleteForm").modal();
        if(confirm("test"));

    });

    });
</script>
</head>
<center>
<?php         
echo "Student List";

?>
<p><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index', 
        'action'=>'add'));?>">Add new student</a></p>
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($this->students as $student) : ?>
<tr>

    <td><?php echo $student->name;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $student->email;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $student->phone;?></td>

    <td>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index', 
            'action'=>'edit', 'id'=>$student->id));?>">Edit</a>
        <a class="delete" href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index', 
            'action'=>'delete','id'=>$student->id));?>">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>

</center>

</html>
```

### IndexController.php

```
<?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
      //  $test = new Application_Model_DbTable_Email();

    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
          $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        $students = new Application_Model_DbTable_Students();
        $this->view->students = $students->fetchAll();
    }

    public function addAction()
    {
        $form = new Application_Form_Student();
        $form->submit->setLabel('Add');
        $this->view->form = $form;

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
                $name = $form->getValue('name');
                $email = $form->getValue('email');
                $phone = $form->getValue('phone');
               // $image = $form->getValue('image');
                $students = new Application_Model_DbTable_Students();
                $students->addStudent($name, $email,$phone);

                $this->_helper->redirector('index');
            } else {
                $form->populate($formData);
            }
        }

    }

    public function editAction()
    {
        $modelStudents = new Application_Model_DbTable_Students();
        $id = (int) $this->_getParam('id');

        $student = $modelStudents->fetch($id);

        $form = new Application_Form_Student($student->email);
        $form->submit->setLabel('Save');
        $this->view->form = $form;
       if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
                $id = (int)$form->getValue('id');
                $name = $form->getValue('name');
                $email = $form->getValue('email');
                $phone = $form->getValue('phone');
                $students = new Application_Model_DbTable_Students();
                $students->updateStudent($id, $name, $email, $phone);

                $this->_helper->redirector('index');
            } else {
                $form->populate($formData);
            }
        } else {
            $id = $this->_getParam('id', 0);
            if ($id > 0) {

                $form->populate($modelStudents->getStudent($id));
            }
        }

    }

    public function deleteAction()
    {

                //$id = $this->getRequest()->getPost('id');
            $students = new Application_Model_DbTable_Students();
            $id = $this->_getParam('id', 0);
            $students->deleteStudent($id);
            $this->_helper->redirector('index');

    }

    //echo $test;

}
```

Thanks in advance,
enamul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using confirm incorrectly, and your posted code also has lots of doubts.
format your links as below

```
 <a class="delete" id="delete_link_<?php echo $student->id?>" href="jacascript:void(0)" onclick="deleteRecord('<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index', 
            'action'=>'delete','id'=>$student->id));?>',<?php echo $student->id?>)">Delete</a>
```

and add this function to your js

```
   <script>
    function deleteRecord(url,id)
    {
      if(confirm('test')){ 
      $.ajax({url:url,success:function(data){alert('Deleted Record')
                                             $("#delete_link_"+id).hide();
                                               }});

      }    
   }
    </script>
```

EDITED :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//
$(document).ready();

  function deleteRecord(url)
        {
          if(confirm('test')){ 
          $.ajax({url:url,success:function(data){alert('Deleted Record')}});
          }    
       }

</script>
```

Comment: I tried this before but the result is same. Could you go through the index.phtml if there is any problem

Thanks for your reply

Comment: @user1559230 sorry i missed confirm previously

Comment: Thanks Rupesh for your reply but it's not working. It gives the following error on browser:

The address wasn't understood
Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (jacascript) isn't associated with any program.
        

        
        

  You might need to install other software to open this address.

Comment: could you please tell me why you are using this:
   href="jacascript:void(0)"

Comment: There was typo in your script that's why the error was shown, I fix it but now the confirmation is not opening when I click to delete

Thanks

Comment: @user1559230 jacascript:void(0) means nothing will happen when you click on the link but the function deleteRecord() will be called

Comment: but it's not working. when i click delete on the link it remains as it is. deleteRecord() was not called

Comment: @user1559230 place simple alert in deleteRecord() function alert the passed url if it not alerted you have placed deleteRecord() at wrong place take a look at page source and check for the function in that

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 //alert("test");
 $(".delete").click(function(e){
  function deleteRecord(url)
  {
  alert("test");
  if(confirm('test')){ 
  $.ajax({url:url,success:function(data)           {alert('Deleted Record')}});
    }
                }
          
 });
 
 });

That is what I did. I don't see any error on that

Comment: it's working now, but I need to refresh the browser to see the changes

Comment: you dont need to place in $(document).ready  place deleteRecord() out of the $(document).ready chec my edited answer

Comment: @user1559230 you will need to hide your delete links after they are deleted by ajax I have edited the answer please have a look on deleteRecord function and also link format

Comment: this is cool, but don't want to use inline javascript. So how to pass the delete_link_id to jQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //alert("test");
    $(".delete").click(function(e){
        //$('p').attrib('id');
        //e.preventDefault();
        //$("#deleteForm").modal();
        if(confirm("test"))
{
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}

});

});
```

Comment: ,Could you tell me how to perform this operation using AJAX ?